# 2022 Q2 Celebrating 10 years blog is untagged

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, blog

The [quarterly 10 years anniversary blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/06/27/celebrating-the-stack-exchange-sites-that-turned-ten-years-old-in-spring-2022/) is up, but it doesn't have any tags at the bottom:

[image]

unlike the [previous one](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/03/16/celebrating-the-stack-exchange-site-that-turned-ten-years-old-in-q1-2022/), which is tagged [community].

Interestingly, the tag *is* shown at the top:

[image]

Comment: The top isn't a tag, it links to [different page](https://stackoverflow.blog/community/), perhaps "section" of some sort (e.g. [podcast](https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast/) also has its own section). In the [actual tag page](https://stackoverflow.blog/tag/community/), the new blog post is not listed.

Comment: You're right; it *looks* like a tag, hence the confusion.

Comment: @Glorfindel thanks I'm checking with Marketing to see if that's an error.

Comment: @Glorfindel well, that's worthy of a separate bug report. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed! The [community](https://stackoverflow.blog/tag/community/) tag has been added:

[image]